# @Override public boolean equals(Object o) "Method does not override and superclass method"

Tags: java

Theoretically this is a really simple (dumb) question...

Compiles successfully:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {return 0;}
```

Error: "Method does not override any superclass method"

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {return true;}
```

It seems to me that if my override of hashCode() compiles the override of equals() should also compile... Obviously I don't understand something relatively fundamental...

What should I look for to resolve this compiler error?

Comment: Both methods should pass compilation with no problem. Are you sure you don't have typos in the actual code?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: I just copy/pasted from the IDE

Comment: Post a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: I copied and pasted from your question and it compiles just fine.

Comment: Please post more details. What IDE are you using, what JDK are you using, what's the result of compiling your class on the command line (using `javac`).

Comment: JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.1.3.0.0

Comment: do you get the error when compiling using `javac` .. either you have a typo which is not present in the question .. or an ide bug.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question - there was something fundamental that wasn't occurring to me:

The cause was that there was another class within the project named Object... and the compiler was rightfully saying that there was no equals() method to override. The strange thing in my mind is why didn't hashCode() exhibit the same behavior?

Nonetheless, my problem is resolved.

Thanks to all who constructively commented or made suggestions...

Comment: The reason that hashCode() didn't have an issue is because it wasn't referencing Object as a parameter (duh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project had a class within the same package as the class exhibiting the compilations issue... this obscured the Java's base Object class (and its equals() method).

Here's the corrected code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj)
{
    return true;
}
```